# compiling outdated PHP yields core dump with OpenSSL functions. OpenSSL version mismatch?

Tags: php, openssl, coredump

I compiled OpenSSL 0.9.8x with these ./config options:

```
./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8 --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8
```

I'm compiling my PHP version with these ./configure options (among others):

```
   --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8
   --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8
```

The problem is that when I run a PHP script with `openssl_public_encrypt` I'm getting a segmentation fault.

Here's what gdb says:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007fd3381c5a48 in RSA_public_encrypt () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

In /usr/local/openssl-0.9.8/lib/ there's libcrypto.so.0.9.8 so why isn't it using that?

Here's my OpenSSL Makefile:

https://pastebin.com/0QSqLCr8

Here's my PHP Makefile:

https://pastebin.com/dGmu0SYZ

Here's a Dockefile that reproduces the issue:

https://pastebin.com/ziZzvTh8

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Which OS do you use? What message does command `ldd path/to/php` shows?,

Comment: @Gasol - OS is debian:wheezy. `ldd /usr/local/bin/php` gives https://pastebin.com/vHN3X55Z as the output.

Comment: @Gasol - here's a Dockerfile that reproduces the issue: https://pastebin.com/ziZzvTh8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will fix the problem in general, but not for yours in this case.

I have rewritten the Dockerfile based on yours in order to fix the segfault.

1. Remove both `--disable-rpath` and `--libdir` arguments on configure phase of PHP.

   We use `rpath` to locate shared objects at runtime for custom build openssl on /usr/local/openssl-0.9.8x.

   See option `-rpath=dir` from  https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld

   > Add a directory to the runtime library search path. This is used when linking an ELF executable with shared objects. All -rpath arguments are concatenated and passed to the runtime linker, which uses them to locate shared objects at runtime. The -rpath option is also used when locating shared objects which are needed by shared objects explicitly included in the link
2. Add `shared` option to config script of OpenSSL

   To build share libraries (libcrypto.so.0.9.8 and libssl.so.0.9.8)
3. Link kerberos libraries only in /usr/kerberos/lib

   Instead of linking all libraries from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu to /usr/kerberos/lib, The ordering of runtime search path is `/usr/kerberos/lib:/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8/lib`

Here is the changes

```
# https://pastebin.com/ziZzvTh8
--- ziZzvTh8.txt    2019-10-08 10:31:33.229217226 +0800
+++ Dockerfile   2019-10-08 12:07:03.271948150 +0800
@@ -8,7 +8,7 @@
     && wget --no-check-certificate http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-0.9.8x.tar.gz \
     && tar xvfz openssl-0.9.8x.tar.gz \
     && cd openssl-0.9.8x \
-    && ./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8 \
+    && ./config shared --prefix=/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8 \
     && make \
     && make install

@@ -23,7 +23,8 @@
     && ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so /usr/lib/ \
     && ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so \
     && mkdir /usr/kerberos \
-    && ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/kerberos/lib
+    && ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 /usr/kerberos/lib
+

 RUN apt-get build-dep -y php5

@@ -43,7 +44,6 @@
        --with-zlib \
        --with-gd \
        --with-pgsql \
-       --disable-rpath \
        --enable-inline-optimization \
        --with-bz2 \
        --with-zlib \
@@ -62,7 +62,6 @@
        --enable-gd-native-ttf \
        --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8 \
        --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8 \
-       --with-libdir=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
        --enable-ftp \
        --with-imap \
        --with-imap-ssl \
@@ -72,4 +71,6 @@
      && make \
      && make install-cli

+ADD test.php /root/test.php
+
 CMD ["bash"]
```

test.php

```
<?php

$key = <<<EOF
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmHzD76i8DA25nC+Qsswi
OM0lW+gViiQD4tEm7suxBc2BGibtdlrsprVIId92hSjQKx4x8+XVWU6k89T5vy8Y
txpXN759OWdGkDi8uvZuYclMjW9Rao+oqSvbXH37R7oSY287I+6uOHclGhniQN3q
RyoXBkbhDk0/FTI/i549q/gGk1UZYv449KLrDOqmtohRcIyAYVnvvWtD1kIzourq
hMtEIrPqwoBqTaUA9kOIXw1jMovao2TN52j48KgOg9KjqtdwUwD9e6n7hJd/subF
6woc8L7zjJFOHH5gacUC7vtiMpBpnSyLQpjFLepYYwftjsRmg4xLdh+Zvgw3xqi4
lwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
EOF;

var_dump(openssl_public_encrypt($data, $crypted, $key));
var_dump($crypted);
```

Result

```
root@7c5df089bcb0:/# php -v
PHP 4.4.9 (cli) (built: Oct  8 2019 04:09:29)
Copyright (c) 1997-2008 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v1.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2004 Zend Technologies

root@7c5df089bcb0:/# php -i | grep OpenSSL
CURL Information => libcurl/7.26.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8x zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.25 libssh2/1.4.2 librtmp/2.3
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Version => OpenSSL 0.9.8x 10 May 2012

root@7c5df089bcb0:/# php /root/test.php
bool(true)
string(256) "W`r�b��e��',뱌Zł^�$�֗��S����w�j�د<������� �)<��j��JL(f@�A���5_S�X=g-?0M�(�d�����+���     �nD*gzË��ڞc'�\'͗�'vnmo�G�Bv�
#~�y D!��lb�t^���| )[za��5���y�G{�\�"

root@7c5df089bcb0:/# ldd `which php` | egrep 'libssl|libcrypto'
        libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/local/openssl-0.9.8/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0x00007efe86da1000)
        libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /usr/local/openssl-0.9.8/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0x00007efe86a0b000)
        libssl.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007efe8401b000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007efe83c21000)

root@7c5df089bcb0:/# objdump -p `which php` | grep RPATH
  RPATH                /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/kerberos/lib:/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8/lib
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that ld-linux resolves the link at runtime to the wrong library.

Try to execute it by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH: 
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/openssl-0.9.8/lib php very_old_php_44_script_which_shall_not_be_used.php`

If it works you might want to execute it using: `LD_DEBUG=all php ...` to check where and why the dynamic linker does not use the 0.9.8 openssl version.

Comment: Setting `LB_LIBRARY_PATH` still resulted in a segfault. `LD_DEBUG=all` gave me 5.63mb of output. Here's a snippet of the output that seems to be relevant to libcrypto.so.1.0.0: https://pastebin.com/6g5xz9Sq

Comment: Here's a Dockerfile that reproduces the issue: https://pastebin.com/ziZzvTh8