# error: '__s1_len' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to compile a really old version of PHP and am getting this error:

```
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: expected ';' before '__s1_len'
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: '__s1_len' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: '__s2_len' undeclared (first use in this function)
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: expected expression before 'const'
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: expected expression before 'const'
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: expected expression before 'const'
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: expected expression before 'const'
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: expected expression before 'const'
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: expected expression before 'const'
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: expected expression before 'const'
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: expected expression before 'const'
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: expected expression before 'const'
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: expected expression before 'const'
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: expected expression before 'const'
/tmp/php-5.0.5/ext/openssl/openssl.c:3198:11: error: expected expression before 'const'
```

Here's line 3198:

```
match = strcmp(cnmatch, buf) == 0;
```

That line looks fine to me? I'm also not seeing `__s1_len` anywhere in the file. Not on line 3198 or on any other line for that matter.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like macros are being use somewhere... either for something on the line or somewhere above.

Comment: You're not going to compile really old versions of PHP with a new OpenSSL unless you do some major hacking. Take it from the person that's been trying to do it for *3 months* without success. Just use PHP 7 or disable SSL.

Comment: @JL2210 - I was compiling against an older version of OpenSSL: http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-0.9.8x.tar.gz I had gotten PHP 4.4 to compile with an older version of OpenSSL but for reasons that are unclear to me it was still linking against OpenSSL 1.0.0: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58099021/569976

Comment: @neubert check out my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/58280319/157675